# How to not mix business logic code with debug/logger code?

Tags: c#, debugging, logging, coding-style

In my programs, I usually need some info telling me what's going on in parts, that is hard to breakpoint, so I use a logger. Is there a way to separate logger code from business code, so we get rid of interlacing e.g. 10 lines of code with 10 lines of logger / debugger code?

Comment: Take a look at Aspect Oriented Programming, in my opinion that's the best thing to remove horizontal concerns. There's multiple frameworks for that, like PostSharp and AspectSharp for example.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [log4net](http://geekswithblogs.net/swisscoder/archive/2012/05/13/c-tutorial-for-log4net-again.aspx) or  [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)  libraries. With this libraries you can work easily, separating a logger layer of bussines layer .

Comment: But with NLog/log4net do I still need to call these libraries code with my own code? In question I mean rather to separate these for example putting logging code in separate assembly or so.